# Java Method creation fails to be read even if working correctly

Tags: java, arrays, swing, methods

I want to create a method where I can simply grab the text from a textfield in my Swing Form. However trying to get it to be recognized by one of my 'if statements' ends up with an error telling me that it cannot find the symbol despite it being defined. I also want to create cleaner code as the way I am doing it does seem to be rather repetitive and messy; Is there a way to shorten the repetitions and call them as variables as well?

```
    public class TextGrabber {
    int [] grabText = {Integer.parseInt(DigitValue.getText())};
    }    

int digit1 = TextGrabber;
    if (digit1 == 1) {
        Digi1.setVisible(false);
        Digi2.setVisible(false);
        Digi3.setVisible(true);
        Digi4.setVisible(false); //This textfield will be hidden
        Digi5.setVisible(false);
        Digi6.setVisible(true);
        Digi7.setVisible(false);
    }

    int digit2 = Integer.parseInt(DigitValue.getText());
    if (digit2 == 2) {
        Digi1.setVisible(true);
        Digi2.setVisible(false);
        Digi3.setVisible(true);
        Digi4.setVisible(true); //This textfield will be hidden
        Digi5.setVisible(true);
        Digi6.setVisible(false);
        Digi7.setVisible(true);
    }

    int digit3 = Integer.parseInt(DigitValue.getText());
    if (digit3 == 3) {
        Digi1.setVisible(true);
        Digi2.setVisible(false);
        Digi3.setVisible(true);
        Digi4.setVisible(true); //This textfield will be hidden
        Digi5.setVisible(false);
        Digi6.setVisible(true);
        Digi7.setVisible(true);
    }

    int digit4 = Integer.parseInt(DigitValue.getText());
    if (digit4 == 4) {
        Digi1.setVisible(false);
        Digi2.setVisible(true);
        Digi3.setVisible(true);
        Digi4.setVisible(true); //This textfield will be hidden
        Digi5.setVisible(false);
        Digi6.setVisible(true);
        Digi7.setVisible(false);
    }

    int digit5 = Integer.parseInt(DigitValue.getText());
    if (digit5 == 5) {
        Digi1.setVisible(true);
        Digi2.setVisible(true);
        Digi3.setVisible(false);
        Digi4.setVisible(true); //This textfield will be hidden
        Digi5.setVisible(false);
        Digi6.setVisible(true);
        Digi7.setVisible(true);
    }

    int digit6 = Integer.parseInt(DigitValue.getText());
    if (digit6 == 6) {
        Digi1.setVisible(true);
        Digi2.setVisible(true);
        Digi3.setVisible(false);
        Digi4.setVisible(true); //This textfield will be hidden
        Digi5.setVisible(true);
        Digi6.setVisible(true);
        Digi7.setVisible(true);
    }

    int digit7 = Integer.parseInt(DigitValue.getText());
    if (digit7 == 7) {
        Digi1.setVisible(true);
        Digi2.setVisible(false);
        Digi3.setVisible(true);
        Digi4.setVisible(true); //This textfield will be hidden
        Digi5.setVisible(false);
        Digi6.setVisible(true);
        Digi7.setVisible(false);
    }

    int digit8 = Integer.parseInt(DigitValue.getText());
    if (digit8 == 8) {
        Digi1.setVisible(true);
        Digi2.setVisible(true);
        Digi3.setVisible(true);
        Digi4.setVisible(true); //This textfield will be hidden
        Digi5.setVisible(true);
        Digi6.setVisible(true);
        Digi7.setVisible(true);
    }

    int digit9 = Integer.parseInt(DigitValue.getText());
    if (digit9 == 9) {
        Digi1.setVisible(true);
        Digi2.setVisible(true);
        Digi3.setVisible(true);
        Digi4.setVisible(true); //This textfield will be hidden
        Digi5.setVisible(false);
        Digi6.setVisible(true);
        Digi7.setVisible(true);
    }
}                                         

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)      {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:

    int AddOneDigit = Integer.parseInt(DigitValue.getText());
    AddOneDigit = AddOneDigit + 1;
    String NewSet = Integer.toString (AddOneDigit);
    DigitValue.setText(NewSet);        
    ShowDigitActionPerformed(evt);

    int check = Integer.parseInt(DigitValue.getText());
    if (check >= 10) {
        check = 0;
        String CheckS = Integer.toString (check);
        DigitValue.setText(CheckS);
        Digi1.setVisible(true);
        Digi2.setVisible(true);
        Digi3.setVisible(true);
        Digi4.setVisible(false); //This textfield will be hidden
        Digi5.setVisible(true);
        Digi6.setVisible(true);
        Digi7.setVisible(true);     
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the masks as an array, and then build it out with something like

```
int digit = Integer.parseInt(DigitValue.getText());
boolean[][] mask = { { false, false, true, false, false, true, false },
        { true, false, true, true, true, false, true },
        { true, false, true, true, false, true, true },
        { false, true, true, true, false, true, false },
        { true, true, false, true, false, true, true },
        { true, true, false, true, true, true, true },
        { true, false, true, true, false, true, false },
        { true, true, true, true, true, true, true },
        { true, true, true, true, false, true, true } };
boolean[] digits = mask[digit - 1];
Digi1.setVisible(digits[0]);
Digi2.setVisible(digits[1]);
Digi3.setVisible(digits[2]);
Digi4.setVisible(digits[3]);
Digi5.setVisible(digits[4]);
Digi6.setVisible(digits[5]);
Digi7.setVisible(digits[6]);
```

I also note you don't have a mapping for digit `'0'`.

Comment: Sorry to trouble you, but I am fairly new to Java. Would you mind expanding on what you meant by storing the masks as an array? The code you wrote out I am assuming will either go in to the main class or public class of the Swing Form, am I correct?

Comment: No worries my friend I figured it out :) thank you for your help!

Comment: I'd even go as far as to use bit masks with it, like 0b001_0010 - it makes it possible to express entire mask as 8 bytes, arguably making it a bit more readable (though it requires a bit shift to access then) and unarguably making it more easily editable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will help you a lot, but you might be able to clean up some of your code by creating a method. You could create a method to declare the visibility of the '*Digi*'s. A method like this may look like the code below.

Code:

```
public void multipleVisibleSet(boolean 1Visible, boolean 2Visible, boolean 3Visible, 
              boolean 4Visible, boolean 5Visible, boolean 6Visible, boolean 7Visible){
  Digi1.setVisible(1Visible);                                 //Add as many as you need
  Digi2.setVisible(2Visible);
  Digi3.setVisible(3Visible);
  Digi4.setVisible(4Visible);
  Digi5.setVisible(5Visible);
  Digi6.setVisible(6Visible);
  Digi7.setVisible(7isible);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but using your code makes java ask for an identifier, would I be right in thinking that the identifier would be (in this case)
    **public void multipleVisibleSet (boolean [] args){
        
    }**